# set Angular Material Radio Button checked within a Radio Button Group

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I've got an Angular Material Radio Button Group with three radio buttons inside.  I need to check one of the buttons.  I thought setting the value of the radio button group would check the corresponding radio button, but its not.  here's what I've got.

HTML template

```
        <mat-radio-group  [formControl]="rbgMarkType" name="MarkType">
            <mat-radio-button value=1>Marked In Field</mat-radio-button>
            <mat-radio-button value=2>No Conflict</mat-radio-button>
            <mat-radio-button value=3>Cancel</mat-radio-button>
        </mat-radio-group>
```

typescript code, attempting to check radio button:

```
export class MtMarkFormComponent implements OnInit {
  ...
  rbgMarkType:FormControl = new FormControl(); 
  ...


ngAfterViewInit() {
 this.SetMarkType();
}

SetMarkType(){
  this.rbgMarkType.patchValue({MarkType:3});//sets value but doesn't check radio button
}
...
}
```

Thanks

Pete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have your `rbgMarkType` as `formControl`

`name="MarkType"` is only there for the name of the `<mat-radio-group>`

```
SetMarkType(){
  this.rbgMarkType.patchValue('3');
}
```